# Error 'Target out of bounds' when connecting through XBee to a server with Node.js/serialport

Tags: node.js, serial-port, xbee, node-serialport

I have an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) module that accepts data on ttyAMA0 of a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) server that is running [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) with 'serialport' installed.

I keep getting an out-of-bounds error from the following code which take an XBee packet up to the length it should be. It then gets sent to another function for checksum validation. But the problem is the darn buffer.

```
var receivingPacket = false;
xbee.on('data', function (data) {
    if(receivingPacket == false && data[0] == 0x7e){
        receivingPacket = true;
        buf = [];
        bufLen = 0;
        bufUsed = 0;
        if(data[3] == 0x90){ //Received Transmission
            bufLen = data[2] + 4; //Start byte, start length byte, end length byte, checksum byte
        }
    }

    if(receivingPacket == true && bufUsed >= bufLen){
        var pBuf = new Buffer(bufUsed); //In case we get another packet right behind it
        var pos = 0;
        for(var i = 0, len = buf.length; i<len; i++){
            try{
                buf[i].copy(pBuf, pos);
            }
            catch(e){ //Sometimes we get a corrupt packet, discard and wait for the next one
                receivingPacket = false;
                console.log(e);
                return false;
            }
            pos += buf[i].length;
        }
        receivingPacket = false;
        processPacket(pBuf);
    }
    else
        if(receivingPacket == true){
            buf.push(data);
            bufUsed += data.length;
        }
});
```

I added the `receivingPacket` as part of testing, it should not be necessary. The problem seems to be the line with [copy](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_targetbuffer_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend), `buf[i].copy(pBuf, pos);`. I don't know if I need to clear the buffer somehow.

The error is

> [RangeError targetStart out of bounds]

which would be pos in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you try to manipulate a position not allocated within the buffer. In this code `buf[i].copy(pBuf, pos);` the position given by `pos` is not in `pBuf`.

Buffers are fixed in size, so you cannot treat them like strings (append/write as much data you like), so when the `targetStart` argument of `copy` happens to greater than BufferLength you get that error.

Not only this, you should check if the copy operation before this error was valid. Most likely it was partially written, due to insufficient space.